# Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException but everything is registered

Tags: xamarin, autofac

I have this portion of code:

```
var _containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
_containerBuilder.RegisterType<NavigationService>().As<INavigationService>();

var container = _containerBuilder.Build();

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var navigationService = scope.Resolve<INavigationService>();
}
```

This is throwing me a runtime exception when I do the resolve:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during
>   the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception
>   for details. Registration: Activator = NavigationService
>   (ReflectionActivator), Services =
>   [MyProject.Services.Navigation.INavigationService], Lifetime =
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership
>   = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> No accessible constructors were found for the type 'MyProject.Services.Navigation.NavigationService'. (See inner
>   exception for details.)

My interface is empty, as is my class that has a parameterless constructor.
My project is a Xamarin.Forms project using .Net standard 2.0 and my version of autofac is the last stable one (4.8.1).

I am clueless as all the sample projects don't seem to do much more.

Like I said, I emptied the class and interface just to see if the problem came from there, but I still have the exception.

```
public interface INavigationService { }

public class NavigationService:INavigationService
 { 

 public NavigationService()
      { 
      }

 }
```

Comment: Please include definition of your class `MyProject.Services.Navigation.NavigationService`, especially constructors (you can skip the rest if it's big). I suspect that all constructors it has are not **public**.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Check my edit, at first I had a few things in my class/interface but I emptied it to see if the problem was there. I have one public constructor. Even with no constructor, I have the exception.

Comment: There should be something more to it. This code absolutely must work. Can you prepare example project showing the error?

Comment: Are you sure NavigationService/INavigationService is not referencing something different (like a NavigationService from Xamarin) when you register it in the container ?

Comment: Yes my INavigationService and NavigationService were mine! but now it works (see my answer), thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

It may sound stupid, but it ended up working after I deleted and recreated my project. I'm sure it was the same classes, as I only copied/pasted.

The only difference is that I had other nugets installed before Autofac in the KO project (ex: EntityFramework Sqlite). In the OK project, my first nuget installation was Autofac.

Comment: Thank you for the comment - this piece of information will be help me do some further diagnostics. I'll periodically get this error after introducing bad code, but once its in this state, I'm unable to resolve it without git clean -xfd and rebuilding my project.